# Crystal Reports SELECT CASE statement

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a switch statement in a Crystal Report that looks like this:

```
stringvar tag := {table1.field1};  //contains a string value

select tag case
  'First Value': {table1.field3}
  'Second Value': {table4.field9}
  default: 'Unknown';
```

But when I try to save the formula, I get this error:

```
---------------------------
Crystal Reports
---------------------------
The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

And it highlights the formula beginning with the single quote before the word "Second" in my example.

What stupid syntax error am I making?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shouldn't this be written as...

```
select (tag )
  case 'First Value': {table1.field3}
  case 'Second Value': {table4.field9}
  default: 'Unknown';
```

?
Note, I just looked the syntax online;  I'm not a Crystal Reports specialist...

Comment: You got it - I was just being obtuse today I guess

Comment: @Joseph   I relate to that, I got them days too :-)  That's where SO is a fine place: we find an audience for discussing both complicated matter or basic-typos-type-of-bugs on these "foggy days".