# Changing Column Text (Crystal)

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

I'm fairly new to Crystal and a user wants me to change column text to tulip if the model is like FT-T*. I figured this would be something fairly easy and tried a few different formulas, but could get them to work. Can you tell me what my formula is doing wrong or what formula I would need to use instead? Thanks.

```
IIF({v_FrameDepartment.cftliner} Like 'FT-T*' THEN {v_FrameDepartment.cftliner} = 'Tulip'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT({v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}, 4)` in your formula to check for a match:

```
IIF(LEFT({v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}, 4) = "FT-T", "Tulip", 
    {v_FrameDepartment.cftliner})
```

It's been a little while since I used CR, so I can't remember if `LEFT` throws an error if you specify a length greater than the length of your string.  If it does, just check the length of `{v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}` first.

Comment: So this doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't change the field text either.

Comment: I'd say narrow the formula down to just `LEFT({v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}, 4)` and see what is getting displayed.  I would have thought that would have worked.

Comment: I did, and then it threw an error, I tried using Replace as well Replace ({v_FrameDepartment.cftliner}, 'FT-T*' , 'Tulip')

Comment: So I did a data refresh and now this works. Is there a way to setup an or statement so that I can replace FT-T with Tulip and FT-V with veneer? Trying multiple things but to little success.

Comment: You should be able to use a `CASE` expression for that; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525420/crystal-reports-select-case-statement) for an example