# How to use Select Case in crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

Hi Developers i'm novice in Crystal Reports and i have a wrote the following code.

```
Select ({Historico.Moeda})
case "MT": 
    if (IntPart = 1) then
        DescDecimal := "Metical"
    else
        DescDecimal := "Meticais";

    if (decimalPart = 0,01) then
        DescInt : = "Centavo"
    else
       DescInt : = "Centavos";
```

default:
    "Metical";

When i trie to view the report i'm getting the following error: **The ) is missing** and I don't know why can anyone please help me. 
I appreciate your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Reports SELECT CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525420/crystal-reports-select-case-statement)

Comment: Be careful with ";" in Crystal, it can end the syntax and might be read as a separate line.